# Limiting Octave console output for large matrices

Tags: octave

Let's say I have a moderately large matrix with data. Around 200k elements.

Whenever I mistakenly input `X` into the console, it locks into a printing loop that lasts minutes (I can't imagine what would be like with a real data matrix with millions of elements); meanwhile languages like python have the much saner default of printing only a few rows from the start & end of such matrices (or lists).

Is there any option (I'm not finding one in the docs) to make this the default behavior? My quality of life using octave will improve a lot.

Comment: In MATLAB, Ctrl+C breaks the printing loop. I think that also works in Octave.

Comment: Well this is true, but let's say there's a little detail I didn't tell: I'm using Emacs and the Octave REPL hangs the whole emacs process if I do the Ctrl-C thing. Hence my question.

Comment: Hmm... I thought pagination was the default. In the GUI and command-line interactive mode, [`more on`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Paging-Screen-Output.html) works. Not sure about emacs.

Comment: Tried more on, I can confirm the emacs output it's all kinds of wrong and no effect is noted. At the same time, console output using more is not exactly what I wanted, but I guess at least I have the option to cancel output early and not spend minutes seeing numbers being print on the screen.

Comment: You can set 'head -n 100' as pager....

Comment: if you change the `PAGER` make sure you change the `PAGER_FLAGS` too. Could be something as simple as `PAGER_FLAGS(' '); PAGER('echo long output disabled')`, or a custom pager script making use of head as Andy suggested etc etc; You can then put this in your .octaverc file for permanent behaviour.